# Find close points to each other in a big List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a big List (like 300000 elements) of struct Node, where Node is defined as

```
public struct Node
{
    public int nid;
    public double x, y, z;
}
```

and I want to know which nodes are close to each other by a certain amount (in the code called gap), in order to organize elements close together in sets.
Please note that for the given nodes distribution every node belong only to one set.

I tried in this way, cycling every node and looking for its neighbours using a Linq query and the classic formula of distance between two points in 3d space, but it is *really* slow.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

```
List<Node> nList;
[...]

for (int i = 0; i < nList.Count; i++) // cycles through all nodes in list
{
    Node nodo_old = nList[i]; // current node

    List<Node> nset = nList.Where(n => (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((n.x - nodo_old.x),2) + Math.Pow((n.y - nodo_old.y), 2) + Math.Pow((n.z - nodo_old.z), 2)) <= gap)).ToList();

    [...]  // now nset contains a list of neighbour nodes
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Travelling salesman problem (Or a variation of), there are no real algorithms that can solve this efficiently and quickly. There are many out there that can do some of it well, and others that do other bits better, but it's a difficult thing. [Check here for more reading on the subject](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Have a check of things like ant colony optimization for a sample alogrithm

Comment: The first and most simple optimization is to immediately rule out any other nodes where the `x`, `y` or `z` independently is further away than `gap` - for those, by rule of geometry, cannot be closer than `gap` itself

Comment: @Draken Is it really a Travelling Salesman-kind problem? There's no optimization or (N-1)! complexity going on here, just plain _O(n^2)_ algorithm.

Comment: It's still a checking of each node to see the distance between each node, true we are not checking the shortest route, but looking at all of those nodes will take time. It was an example to point out that this won't be an easy problem to solve using just LinQ, this will take an algorithm to improve the speed

Comment: @Nobody See https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Comment: Sorting list first by z can reduce the number square root calculations.  Any z distance greater than gap can be eliminated.  You can then repeat by x and y to eliminate more Nodes.

Comment: I like it so much by the way ^_^

Comment: Do you need to Sqrt the sum, Because you are only looking for relative sizes  couldn't you just square `gap` once at the start and compare <= to that?

Comment: "*Please note that for the given nodes distribution every node belong only to one set.*". That doesn't make sense, there can be numerous nodes that are within a certain distance of more than one node, so what criteria would you use to decide the set they should belong to?

Comment: Rather than calculating 3D distance (Sqrt of sum of squares) consider calculating the angle between two vectors from the origin to each of two points (normalized to length 1).  This is a simple (fast) dot product and gives you the inverse cosine of the angle; cosines close to 1 are vectors that are "close together" and will give you an initial group of clustered points to work with.

Comment: @InBetween a criteria for categorizing in unique sets is simply a "closeness" threshold.  All nodes within X distance of any node in that set are in the set; nodes further than X distance from any node in the set are in some other set.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering

Comment: @DanielWiddis The OP is asking for an algorithm that does the following: given a set of nodes, obtain *for each node* the set of nodes that are closer than a given distance. *Each node must appear only in **one** set*. I still can't see the logic in it; there is bound to be nodes that will belong to more than one set: `N1` is close to `N2` which is in turn close to `N3` but `N1` is not close to `N3`. `N2` will belong to `N1`'s cluster but it will also belong to `N3`'s cluster. How do you deal with `N2` only being assignable to one set?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. At the end I modified the rest of  the code in order to avoid completly using any linq query since they are so slow with big collections.
edit: By the way the code has to deal with a particular mesh for a finite element program, so i know that each node is contained only in one set of nodes close together.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm removes the checked nodes to decrease processing time. I didn't try it on your problem but I'm sure it will help you because I tested it on another scenario and it works perfectly.

```
// to hold sets of neighbour nodes
Dictionary<int, List<Node>> relatedCollectionsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<Node>>();
int index = 0;

List<Node> nList;

while (nList.Any())
{
    var relatedCollection = nList.Where(n => (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((n.x - nList.First().x), 2) + Math.Pow((n.y - nList.First().y), 2) + Math.Pow((n.z - nList.First().z), 2)) <= gap));

    List<Node> relatedCollectionList = relatedCollection.ToList();
    List<Node> relatedCollectionListForDictionary = relatedCollection.ToList();

    relatedCollectionsDictionary.Add(index++, relatedCollectionListForDictionary);

    while (relatedCollectionList.Any())
    {
        nList.Remove(relatedCollectionList.First());
        relatedCollectionList.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

The idea is that you do a lot of processing and iterate through all nodes every time. But using this scenario you don't iterate through any item more than one time.

Comment: Actually, you will go through lots of items more than once, until you put them in a collection. This is a good idea, but the implementation has a lot of DRY violations and funny design choices?